# What type of art style is featured in this image from DomiNations?

Tags: style-identification

What is the name of this style of art below? Any additional information on techniques used to create similar artwork in the image below would be a bonus!

[image: game character art]
<sub>(source: [adweek.com](http://www.adweek.com/socialtimes/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/10/DomiNations-2.png))</sub>

I feel it is definitely not pixel art or vectors. Perhaps it is painted? But I'm not entirely sure.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking for the name of this style, or for what techniques are used to create images like this?

Comment: I would use a 3D modeling program for something like this; they definitely look like renders to me.

Comment: @user568458 Name of this style would be helpful so I can do some further googling. Any additional explanation of techniques would be a bonus!

Comment: It's a photo of 3D models as John said most likely. As for the "style" of it, that is very broad because there's no one style in this photo that I can tell. What "style" are you asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an isomorphic-3d-computer-generated rendering of wargame figures in a cartoon style.

Comment: Thanks Yorik! It seems so obvious now that y'all told me its 3D rendered haha

Comment: It looks like some form soft focus has been applied to it after the 3D rendering to soften it and make it look more painted. That style is common with "casual gaming" fantasy games, it makes them look more casual and less serious or geeky (more Candy Crush and less World of Warcraft)

Comment: they look a lot like lead miniatures circa 1980. see "ral partha" for instance